# Function Defined in Terms of Metric is Continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be some metric space, and let $f : X \to X$ be such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \le ad(x,y)$ for every $x,y \in X$, where $a \in (0,1)$. I am trying to show that $g : X \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = d(f(x),x)$ is continuous by cleverly adding zero and using the triangle inequality. I realize that writing $g$ as composition of continuous functions is easier, but I am trying to get more practice with the triangle inequality. Here is my attempt.

\begin{align*} 
|d(f(x),x) - d(f(y),y)| & = \left|\bigg(d(f(x),x) - d(x,y)\bigg) + \bigg(d(x,y) - d(f(y),y) \bigg) \right| \\ 
& \le |d(f(x),x) - d(x,y)| + |d(x,y) - d(f(y),y)| \\ 
& \le d(f(x),y) + d(f(y),x) \\ 
& \le d(f(x),x) + d(x,y) + d(f(y),y) + d(x,y) \\ 
& \le 2(a+1)d(x,y), \\ 
\end{align*}

First of all, is this right? Secondly, is there way better way to add zero and use the triangle inequality? The factor of $2(a+1)$ doesn't seem tight enough.

Comment: Why not: $d(f(x), x) - d(f(x), y) + d(f(x), y) - d(f(y), y)$

Comment: Draw an XxX graph together with the diagonal. Then you can see if a better bound can be found. There is a square around $(x,f(x))$ that contains $(y,f(y))$.

Comment: Why be cleaver when it is so easy to note that f is continuous and g is a composition of continuous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary $x$ and $y \ ,$ 
$$d(f(y),y) \leq d(f(y),f(x))+d(f(x),y)\leq d(f(y),f(x))+d(f(x),x)+d(x,y) \ .$$
Subtract to get
$$d(f(y),y)-d(f(x),x) \leq d(f(y),f(x))+d(x,y) \leq ad(y,x)+d(x,y)$$

Since the same holds with roles of a and y reversed, we get

$$|d(f(y),y)-d(f(x),x)| \leq (a+1)d(x,y) \ . $$

This shows that $g$ is Lipschitz with constant $Lip(f)+1$ .